# How to access a variable outside of a class function if it wasn't passed to the function

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have been tasked to modify the behavior of a function in one of our Python classes.

Our function takes a few parameters, one being a debug flag. Currently the if the debug flag is not specified then we assume it to be False. What we need it to do is when debug is not specified, check the variable "debug" from the calling code and use that value, if it exists.

I would simply change the name of the debug parameter in the function declaration, except that we have a lot of legacy code that uses that flag.

This is in Jupyter Lab, if it makes any difference.

Sample code:

```
class MyClass:
    
    @classmethod
    def fn(self, debug=None):

        if debug is None:
            try:
                debug = parent.debug
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                debug = "BAD"
        return debug

debug = True

x = myClass
print( x.fn() )
```

I would want the output to be "True" but it ends up being:

```
global name 'parent' is not defined  
BAD
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: What do you *intend* `parent` to be?? It sounds like you want dynamic scope, but python doesn't support dynamic scope (which is a *good* thing). You could do something hacky like introspect the call stack, but I don't understand what exactly you want to change. Why can't you add an additional parameter?

Comment: It isn't clear from your [mre] whether `parent` is in the same scope as the class instance. Please provide a mre. [4.2.2. Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names). [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). if you are trying to access the module variable, `debug`, don't preface it with parent.

Comment: I should add this is in a Python v2.7.13 environment.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: When the fn function is called and the parameter debug is not specified, get the value of the variable debug from the global scope. In other words, if we didn't tell the function to debug or not, try and find out if we should be debugging based on the variable debug in the calling code.

Comment: So, saying "calling code" implies something different than just the global variable but thanks for following up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `globals()['debug']` instead.

Or replace your fn() method to:

```
@classmethod
def fn(self, debug=None):

    if debug is None:
        debug = globals().get('debug', 'BAD')

    return debug
```

Comment: No, because you already has `debug` local variable

Comment: Ah. Yes, you are right. I still think the OP wants to access the value in an arbitrary caller's scope, but hopefully they can clarify

Comment: This appears to work for me. I am now returning the correct value from my function when debug is not passed as a parameter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You access variable parent which us not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the MyClass in your code isn't inherited from any other class. Technically, the class doesn't have any parent(except the obj class by default), so it's impossible to access something that doesn't exist like 'parent.debug'. Secondly, as for your problem, I'm assuming that you want to access the debug variable that is initialized outside the class then you can easily do that by doing something like this:

```
global debug
class MyClass:
     @classmethod
     def fn(self, debug=None):
         if debug is None:
             try:
                 debug = debugOut
             except Exception as e:
                 print(e)
                 debug = "BAD"
     return debug
debugOut = True
x = MyClass()
print(x.fn())
```

The above code returns True